# CSS not running in mermaid JS,

Tags: html, css

I am just learning `mermaid.js` and this is some simple code. I declare a `cssClass` in the `div` to add do some styles, but the `cssClass` is not working.

I also want do some animation in this flowchart but I couldn't: I cannot find any source for animation. How I can do animation in this flow chart?

```
<style>
    .cssClass>rect {
        fill: #FF0000;
        stroke: #FFFF00;
        stroke-width: 4px;
    }
</style>

<div class="mermaid">
    graph TD;
    A-->B;
    class A cssClass;
    style B fill:green,stroke:RED,stroke-width:4px
</div>
```

I do not understand the problem: Why is CSS not working?

Comment: Please put your code into the snippet.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is CSS priority problem.Mermaid.js has default css.This CSS class priority is higher than you defined.If you want your css work.The easy way is add "!important".

```
<style>
.cssClass>rect {
    fill: #FF0000 !important;
    stroke: #FFFF00 !important;
    stroke-width: 4px !important;
}
```